# Need Help figuring out why Firemonkey style for checkbox never displays the check

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using Firemonkey in Delphi 11 and wanted to modify the checkbox to use a path rather than a text "X"

Using the original checkbox style as basis, I modified it so that it contained the following:

```
object TLayout
  StyleName = 'checkboxstyle'
  Align = Center
  Size.Width = 149.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 30.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  TabOrder = 89
  object TLayout
    Align = Left
    Size.Width = 20.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 30.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    object TRectangle
      StyleName = 'background'
      Align = Top
      Fill.Color = xFFC9C9C9
      Locked = True
      HitTest = False
      Padding.Bottom = 1.000000000000000000
      Margins.Left = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 2.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 2.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 16.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 16.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      Stroke.Color = xFF282727
      XRadius = 2.000000000000000000
      YRadius = 2.000000000000000000
      object TPath
        StyleName = 'checkmark'
        Align = Client
        Data.Path = {
          2A0000000000000000E0D8440000FF440100000000E0B5440000DC4401000000
          008093440060FE440200000000A0804400A00845020000000000614400601045
          0200000000C05F44006010450200000000405E44006010450200000000804C44
          00400C45020000000040384400200745010000000080134400E0FB4401000000
          004058440080D9440200000000007E4400A0C6440200000000808E4400A0B644
          0200000000808E4400E0B5440200000000808E440040B5440200000000C07D44
          0000A5440200000000C0574400009244010000000080124400C05E4401000000
          00803844008038440100000000405E44004012440100000000E0914400C05744
          020000000000A54400C07D44020000000040B54400808E440200000000E0B544
          00808E440200000000A0B64400808E440200000000A0C64400007E4402000000
          0080D944004058440100000000E0FB4400801344010000000020074500403844
          0200000000400C4500804C44020000000060104500405E440200000000601045
          00805F44020000000060104500C060440200000000A008450060804402000000
          0060FE44004093440100000000E0DB4400C0B544010000000000FF4400E0D844
          010000000000114500E0FB440100000000700745008007450100000000E0FB44
          000011450100000000E0D8440000FF440300000000E0D8440000FF44}
        Fill.Color = x00303030
        Margins.Left = 3.000000000000000000
        Margins.Top = 3.000000000000000000
        Margins.Right = 3.000000000000000000
        Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 10.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 10.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Stroke.Kind = None
        object TColorAnimation
          Duration = 0.100000001490116100
          PropertyName = 'Fill.Color'
          StartValue = x00303030
          StopValue = xFF303030
          Trigger = 'IsChecked=true'
        end
        object TColorAnimation
          Duration = 0.000099999997473788
          PropertyName = 'Fill.Color'
          StartValue = xFF303030
          StopValue = x00303030
          Trigger = 'IsChecked=false'
        end
      end
    end
  end
  object TText
    StyleName = 'text'
    Align = Client
    Locked = True
    HitTest = False
    Margins.Left = 1.000000000000000000
    Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
    Margins.Right = 1.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 127.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 28.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Text'
    TextSettings.FontColor = claSilver
    TextSettings.HorzAlign = Leading
    TextSettings.VertAlign = Leading
  end
end
```

However, when I apply this style to a checkbox, regardless as to the IsChecked setting the check never displays.  Conversely, if I set its color to not have an alpha mask then then the check appears but doesn't go away if I uncheck the box.

Any insight as to what is going on, and how to fix this would be GREATLY appreaciated.

Comment: First you need to provide a [mre], so that the problem can be replicated and investigated. Pay attention to *minimal* but it still must be *complete* so it can be copy - pasted into the IDE. Secondly, you need to be clear on what exactly you have changed: a) Which style did you use as starting point? b) What changes did you do to that style? c) Did you check each modification before moving to the next? Which ones worked? Etc.

Comment: I thought the code sample was sufficient to reproduce it as you can just paste that into a stylebook.  That said, I have figured out the issue.  There appears to be yet another bug in FireMonkey -- I know SHOCKING -- where having ANY of the elements in a style sheet having HITTEST = TRUE seems to prevent the animations from triggering.  But wait, you cry, there is NO HitTest=true in the above style sheet.  True, but the path Element has no HitTest entry and apparently the default is TRUE and that's what breaks it.

Comment: So, if I read between your lines, adding `HitTest = False` to the path object fixes the problem? How will that affect the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in TCheckBox.TryValueIsChecked which uses TryStrToBool to pass a string boolean value. However 'true' and 'false' (used by style triggers) are not defined in the boolean strings. Adding the following code to your program's startup should work-around the problem until it's fixed.

```
var
  BoolLen: Integer;
begin
  BoolLen := Length(TrueBoolStrs);
  SetLength(TrueBoolStrs, BoolLen + 1);
  TrueBoolStrs[BoolLen] := 'true';
  BoolLen := Length(FalseBoolStrs);
  SetLength(FalseBoolStrs, BoolLen + 1);
  FalseBoolStrs[BoolLen] := 'false';
end;
```